# pandas TimeGrouper custom frequency time range

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

How do I implement grouping data by custom time range? I was able to group the data by the hour, but I want to group it at 1 hour and 1 minute intervals.

Something like this code:
`df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H:1Min')).mean()`
(But this returns an error.)

My objective is to get the average values per `1H:1Min` intervals. Hope you could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `3660` seconds

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('3660S')).mean()
```

Or `61` minutes

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('61Min')).mean()
```

Or what @root said in comments

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H1Min')).mean()
```

---

Consider the data frame `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10), pd.date_range('2017', periods=10, freq='30Min'))
```

All groupings yield

```
                       0
2017-01-01 00:00:00  1.0
2017-01-01 01:01:00  3.5
2017-01-01 02:02:00  5.5
2017-01-01 03:03:00  7.5
2017-01-01 04:04:00  9.0
```

Comment: Or `1H1Min` (or `1H1T`) is the proper way to combine frequency aliases.

Comment: I apologize if this may be a simple question. I am just new to pandas and programming in general, still reading the documentation. I did not realize I could just use 3660s or 1H1Min. Stuck into overanalyzing. Many thanks!

Comment: @EmmanD. please don't apologize!  You've done what many are afraid to do.  And that is risk looking foolish.  There is nothing foolish about trying to rid yourself of ignorance.  It was a fine question.